# Is it a good idea to apply swipe-based list actions on an activity feed list?

Tags: actions

I am designing UX for an activity feed on a mobile app. The height of each feed/activity item will vary, and should include actions like share, like, etc. The straight-forward approach for implementing these actions would be an action bar at the bottom of each feed item. However, I am considering to earn some more real estate (as well as add some gestural quality) by enclosing these actions in a swipe gesture, e.g.:

http://www.scrubly.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/feb2_2.jpg
http://www.futuretap.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Where-To-Swipe-Actions1.jpg

This works well when applied to lists that are made up of list-items of fixed height. However, since the height of activity items on my feed will vary, I am wondering if this is a good idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a major problem with this approach. If you hide action items( like, share) that are of real importance, you won't get enough likes and shares as they are a swipe away and user has to come back to normal UI by swiping back once he/she's done with the action.

So I think you should keep such items in direct visibility of the user to obtain maximum likes and shares.

Also you will have to show the number of likes and shares for a particular feed which becomes hard for a user to see in current scenario. I would like to show straight away to the user that how famous a feed is.

Comment: @Rosmerist Did I solve your problem. If yes, there is a system to upvote here.